# Safari keeps warning "malicious javascript detected on this domain"

Tags: safari

Safari keeps warning `malicious javascript detected on this domain`, and there is only a `OK` button to click. 
It is stupid to click `OK` again and again.
How to prevent this?

I think the so-called `malicious javascript` is just some code for ads, because I saw this warning at a few websites of large company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript of Baidu Ad and Statistics are redirected to GitHub urls https://github.com/greatfire/ and https://github.com/cn-nytimes/ It is in fact DDoS due to large population. 
GitHub returns an alert page in order to stop the recursive JS running for each user. 
This is possibly done by GFW (Great Fire Wall) as the two URLs are not welcomed by them and only people outside mainland China faced this issue today. (GitHub cannot function well in China).
A detailed analysis can be found on WooYun (in Simplified Chinese)
http://drops.wooyun.org/papers/5398

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That's it. I found a report about this, and this may be caused by the Great Fire Wall, since it's normal in China.

Comment: @jherran the answer is not behind the link, but the URL itself is the answer.

Comment: @jherran the url ~/greatfire/ means China Great Fire Wall. one of the guess is that GFW hijacked Baidu js and redirect to ~/greatfire/ and ~/cn-nytimes/ as these two sites are not welcomed by Chinese Government.

Comment: So is it still safe to use that website?

Comment: @curioususer Yeah, it's OK, just the annoying arguments between github and the GFW.